# Error when installing github module via pip

Tags: python, github, pip, anaconda

I'm trying to download a python module from github using pip, but I seem to be running into problems upon download:

```
00000@ubuntu-00000:~/Desktop/Python/Blockchain.data$ pip install git+https://github.com/luke-jr/eloipool.git
You are using pip version 7.0.3, however version 7.1.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Collecting git+https://github.com/luke-jr/eloipool.git
  Cloning https://github.com/luke-jr/eloipool.git to /tmp/pip-f159a1wz-build
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 18, in <module>
      File "/home/00000/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/tokenize.py", line 438, in open
        buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-f159a1wz-build/setup.py'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-f159a1wz-build
```

Any insight into why this isn't installing?

Comment: This project did not provide a `setup.py`, so you can not install it by `pip`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Module did not contain a setup.py file.

Ended up doing:

```
git clone https://ADDRESS .
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar problem when installing selenium recently. Firstly upgrade your PIP. Then try installing what ever you are trying to install.